# Call module without shell

Tags: python, django, program-entry-point

In some of my django utility classes, I want to define a main method such that I can call my module without having to use the shell. (Call `__name__ == "__main__"`) Is this even possible?  If so, how can I make this call?

```
from django.conf import settings

... # Define module code here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(settings.DEBUG)
    # interact with classes defined in this module which require django classes
```

Comment: Write custom [django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: add `sys.path.append("/path/to/MyModule.py")` then you can `import MyModule`

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean. In general, you can write programmes which use the django infrastructure, and run separately from your django application (in the sense that they won't serve up any content), but can still e.g. affect the data in your database. You can do that in the way you propose.

If you want to interact with your running django service, a custom command may be more appropriate.